# Problem with the Table of contents in the first page of each chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, report

I have a problem with my table of contents in the first page of each chapter.

This is my main page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, notitlepage]{report}

%==================================  PACKAGES  =========================================================================================================

    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                                                               
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}               
     \usepackage{url}                                             
     \usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
     \usepackage{enumitem}                                                    
     \usepackage{fancyhdr}                                
     \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{titletoc}
    \usepackage{epigraph}
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \usepackage{lmodern}



%===================================================================


\newlength\ChapWd
\settowidth\ChapWd{\huge\chaptertitlename}



\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filcenter\sffamily}
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    {
    \node[fill=DarkBlue,font=\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east,minimum size=\ChapWd]
      at ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=-15pt]current page.north east)
      (numb) {\thechapter};
    \node[rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt,font=\huge] at (numb.west) {\chaptertitlename};
    }
  }{0pt}{\textsc{\fontsize{33}{40}\selectfont\color{DarkBlue}#1}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{50pt}{10pt}


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ttl@printlist}{\endgroup}{{\noindent\color{DarkBlue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\vskip30pt\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\DoPToC{%
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\noindent{\color{DarkBlue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\par\medskip}%
}

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize\itshape}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoftables
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{./intro.tex}
\end{document}
```

In each chapter i add `\DoPToC`.
The first chapter(intro.tex):

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Introduction}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{Introduction}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{}
\epigraph{A brainy quote -- Its Author}{}
\DoPToC


 \setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}

%============= Contexte et objectifs:   ==============%


\section*{Contexte et objectifs:}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Contexte et objectifs}
```

And in the pdf document I have this result:

[image]

how can i have juste table of contiens without chapter*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments, they make it very hard for people to help you. Instead edit your question to put the fragment into a small compilable document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows the problem. If this code is from a non-standard document class, post a link to it.

Comment: That's still not a compilable document. And it's awfully large. Remove all the code and packages that aren't needed to show the specific problem at hand.

Comment: ok I will do it

Comment: Thanks for trimming down the example. But this doesn't produce the weird output in the chapter TOC, so it's hard to know what is causing the problem.